# Update branch in git

Tags: git, github

I am working in a branch `my_branch` and I want to merge all updates from the `develop` branch into it, without deleting my non-common files (which are only in my branch).
How can that be done?

EDIT: Just to be clear: I want to merge the updates from `develop` into `my_branch`, without changing anything in `develop`.

Comment: `git stash`, `git pull`, `git stash apply` may works, but as usual with git check first what doing stash before trying it

Comment: you can stash your changes momentarily, merge the branch and then apply them back onto the merged branch.

Comment: so should I run git stash on my_branch and then git_pull on develop, and go back to my branch and git stash apply?

Comment: Yep: `git checkout my_branch && git stash && git checkout develop && git puill && git checkout my_branch && git stash apply`. There is surely a quicker way, but it should works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have checked out your feature branch or working branch (my_branch), and you have some **local uncommitted changes** which you do not want to lose while merging the develop branch onto it, you can temporarily 'stash' them.

`git stash`

> **Stashing**
>
> Often, when you’ve been working on part of your project, things are in a messy state and you want to switch branches for a bit
>   to work on something else. The problem is, you don’t want to do a
>   commit of half-done work just so you can get back to this point later.
>   The answer to this issue is the git stash command.
>
> Stashing takes the dirty state of your working directory — that is,
>   your modified tracked files and staged changes — and saves it on a
>   stack of unfinished changes that you can reapply at any time.

Afterwards, when doing a `git status` you see that there is nothing to commit anymore. The working directory is clean again.

Then you can go ahead and merge the develop branch onto your branch.

`git merge develop`.

Then, apply these stashed changes back onto your branch (my_branch).

`git stash apply`

At no point, changes will have been made to your develop branch.